# Remove space between 2 columns and insert commas - bash

Tags: bash

I am using:

```
cut -f1-2 input.txt|sed 1d
```

The data is outputting like this:

```
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/     fd0977d5855d1295bd57383b17981a09
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/     fd34c32786aadab513f506c30c2cba33
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/     fe7d03512e0731e40be628524efbf317
```

I am trying to get it to output without a space like this and insert a comma between the file path and md5 check sum so excel can separate it properly:

```
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/,fd0977d5855d1295bd57383b17981a09
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/,fd34c32786aadab513f506c30c2cba33
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/,fe7d03512e0731e40be628524efbf317
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't see your input.txt, but try this line, do the job in one shot:

```
awk -v OFS="," 'NR>1{print $1,$2}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This can make it:

```
$ tr -s " " < your_file | sed 's/ /,/g'
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/,fd0977d5855d1295bd57383b17981a09
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/,fd34c32786aadab513f506c30c2cba33
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/,fe7d03512e0731e40be628524efbf317
```

`tr -s " " < your_file` removes extra spaces. `sed 's/ /,/g'` replaces spaces with commas.

Comment: thank you for explaining what it does, I never used "tr" before. thanks